# ISAPI Rewrite With Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, azure, azure-web-app-service, isapi-rewrite

I'm not sure if this is the best/correct place for this type of question. But I have an existing .NET website which I am moving from our dedicated EC2 server to an Azure Web App.

However, this current site uses an .htaccess file with about 200 redirects (*301 from old urls to new ones*) which is powered by ISAPI rewrite (*Which was installed manually on the Win2008 server*).

I need to keep these redirects, but wondering how everyone else deals with permanent Url redirects on .NET applications when moving to an Azure Web App (*From a dedicated server that had ISAPI rewrite installed*)?

Putting them all in the web.config seems a little odd to me? And I don't know how that would affect performance?

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2):

I always put them in the web.config.
If you think it will be too messy, you can put them in a separate file and use the `configSource` attribute to link to the file.

Comment: How many is the most you have had in there? Did you notice any performance issues?

Comment: The most I've had was something between 100 and 200, but that was done with [Rewrite Maps](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module). We didn't measure the performance, but the site is not slow today so my guess is it does not impact performance much.

Comment: Also, 301 redirects will be cached by the browser, so the user will not get redirected after the first visit. The browser will translate the url before the request is sent.